# Hyper-V Test DC: access via RDP from production domain

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop, domain-controller

i got a little trouble with a test setup i want to do using Hyper-V.
Its supposed to be running within an active domain network. I want to setup a DC and other Servers - so normaly i would choose a internal or private network. 
However: I also want to be able to access the VMs using RDP, thisfor i would have to use a external network configuration. But if i do so there would be two DCs and two DHCPs in the network, which would cause trouble.

So, my question: is there any way to realize what i want to do or do i have to use the Hyper-V Manager to access the VM's?

Comment: Are you saying you want them exposed to the internet via RDP ports?

Comment: Need more clarification here re: your current network setup and what you're trying to do or this is getting closed.

Comment: @gravyface - a bit harsh, don't you think? It's a common enough problem that's easy enough to understand from the question if you've been through it yourself.

Comment: @Steve: it's not clear what he wants: as DanBig asks, does he want external/outside access to RDP?  Is he trying to setup a _different_ test domain in a test environment along side a production domain?

Comment: consider the company domain called corporate.org and the virtual hyper-v domain i want to use as a test environment test.org. i want to run a DC within test.org (creating test.org) AND i want to connect via RDP to any machine within test.org FROM corporate.org WITHOUT affacting DHCP / AD or any other productive service of corporate.org. 

If you need any more details it would be helpful to write which kind of details since its clear to me thought.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've taken in the past is to:

- Keep the VMs on an Internal network
- Install TS Gateway on the Parent Partition to provide RDP connectivity

Comment: thanks, that sound like a solution i will definitely  consider. but i'm curious if there might be a better one. I was thinking about using a virtual VLAN switch on the host which should be able to do the job with the right setting, i just dont know how to realize it.